# How Consesus is reached in Hyperledger

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, consensus

In Hyperledger fabric consensus is acheived by orderers but on what basis each transaction is ordered and How many orderers are present in distributed network if there are more than one again how ordering done by each orderers are identical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> on what basis each transaction is ordered

Each transaction is ordered by an ordering service node, where it uses its internal implementation-specific consensus mechanism.

Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 comes with 2 ordering service implementations:

- Solo orderer -- mainly used for development and testing; has 1 node and simply batches the transactions into blocks
- Kafka based orderer -- the orderer nodes send the transactions to a kafka queue from which all orderer nodes "pull" the transactions in the same order, and then cut the same blocks; each orderer sends into the queue a "time to cut a block" message, and then when the first message reaches the queue, a block is cut by all ordering service nodes

In the future there will probably be a Byzantine tolerant implementation of the ordering service based on the sBFT (simplified pBFT) algorithm.